# Nested angular reactive form components but add FormControls flat on parent form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

So I basically I have a large form and want to split it up into multiple sub-form components. Nothing special so far.
Consider this target data structure:

```js
{
    additionalProps: {
        prop1: any
        prop2: any,
        ...
    }
    modifierType: enum,
    modifierProp1: any,
    modifierProp2: any,
    modifierProp3: any,
    ...
}
```

Depending on which `modifierType` I select I can get different `modifierProps`.

So far I read a lot about the `ControlValueAccessor` interface and have a somewhat functioning abstract `ControlValueAccessorBase` implementation of it that I could use for any sub-form component that represents an object in my data structure, e.g. `additionalProperties`. Now I want to create a modifier-selection.component that implements my abstract `ControlValueAccessorBase` without getting a structure like this:

```js
{
   additionalProps: {
       prop1: any
       prop2: any,
       ...
   }
   modifier: {
       modifierType: enum,
       modifierData: {
           modifierProp1: any,
           modifierProp2: any,
           modifierProp3: any,
           ...
       }
   }
}
```

My minimalistic HTML for the modifier-selector.component looks something like the following (which I get if I implement my abstract ControlValueAccessorBase on all sub-components):

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-select formControlName="type"></mat-select>
    <modifier-A *ngIf="this.form.controls['type'].value === ModifierType.A" formControlName="modifierData"></modifier-A>
    <modifier-B *ngIf="this.form.controls['type'].value === ModifierType.B" formControlName="modifierData"></modifier-B>
</div>
```

Note:
I can't change the target data structure because of backwards compatability and I really want to avoid mapping my data between the two structures. But the goal here really is to learn how to create an abstract `ControlValueAccessor` that can also write it's child FormControls "flat" onto the "root" form.

Comment: Could you actually provide a [mcve] of what you have working now?